# Django server on local ubuntu server cannot be reached from another windows machine

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, lan

I am trying to deploy Django project on **Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS** with

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

also tried

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.103:8000
```

The *server starts*, however i cannot reach it on another machine(**Windows 7**) in the same LAN. I am thinking that LAN is working properly, because i use **ssh** to connect ubuntu server and working through it. The **/etc/network/interfaces** file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The **ifconfig**:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:31:e5:99:89
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

I tried accessing ***192.168.0.103:8000*** in browser on Windows but nothing.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can SSH in then most likely this means that your 8000 port is not open on the server, try this [Ubuntu iptables guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

If your SSH works, then you can also use port forwarding through SSH

`ssh user@server -L 8000:server:8000`

This is the the `ssh user@host -L localport:host:hostport` format

This will forward the 8000 port from your server, to your 8000 port locally, through the SSH tunnel, and in which case on your browser you'd use `127.0.0.1:8000` or `localhost:8000`(as opposed to using the host/IP of the server)